# Replace Activity in Manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest

When I Run My application it will run the MainActivity first as per the ManiFest.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="bizsalt.drawer2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/gargi_blue"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="XYZ"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

It's work fine But Now I want to *add* **SplashScreenActivity** , **LoginActivity** and **RegisterActivity** *before* the MainActivity.

So How I can `Change the Order of Activity`. First start Application with the SplashScreenActivity then **LoginActivity** and **RegisterActivity** and then The **MainActivity**.

---

If I use this code It work fine But Title is displayed. How to remove it.

```
CircularProgressView progressView2;
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 5000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Remove the Title Bar
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from splash_screen.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);


    CircularProgressView progressView2 = (CircularProgressView)findViewById(R.id.progress_view10);
    progressView2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {


        @Override
        public void run() {

            finish();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        package="bizsalt.drawer2">

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/gargi_blue"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".LoginActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
              />
             <activity
                android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
              /> 
             <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
              />
    </application>
    </manifest>
```

And in your SplashScreenActivity. Put code to transit to LoginActivity:

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(mIntent);
```

Do same with other Activity

Comment: I try this But App crash.

Comment: Please post your logcat

Comment: Please read this link:http://developer.android.com/intl/vi/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Let requestWindowFeature between super.Oncreate and setcontentview()

Answer (score 0):

> So How I can Change the Order of Activity

**you can not change order of activity from `manifest`**, you can define launcher activity but from there after you need to write your own logic and code in java file.

Before doing anything in JAVA file you need to define your activity in manifest file

`Intent` will be used for launching new `Activity`. Check below links for more information.

[Intent](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

[Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/intl/in/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
            android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
            android:label="XYZ"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

<activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity "
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

<activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
```

and in your splash screen open whichever activity you want to open like via button click or timer and thing for other activities also.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
android:name=".MainActivity"
```

in your manifest.xml file to

```
android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
```

In SplashScreenActivity, add this lines of code after the Splash screen has completely loaded

```
Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(loginIntent);
```

In the LoginActivity, if user logs in successfully move to Mainactivity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

The log says the solution also

Don't call `setContentView()` before `requestFeature()`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you haven't added all of your activities in manifest file.If you don't do that and still call activity from intent your app crahses.
So first thing is the activity you want at very first,pass intent filter for the same as below:

```
   <activity
                android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
```

Secondly whatever activity you create add it to manifest and now dont give filter for any other.Add it this way

```
<activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="XYZ"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
              />
```

Thirdly pass intent from your current activity to the activity you want to switch

```
   Intent int = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(int);
```

If still any problem occurs post your logcat.
Good luck!!